# SSIS on Azure - how to execute a process task on Azure?

Tags: azure, ssis, azure-data-factory

I'm running SSIS in an Azure datafactory / SQL managed instance environment and want to lift and shift my existing ETL to Azure from an on-premise environment.

Currently I have an executable that performs a number of tasks and is run as part of the SSIS package as a process task - no trouble at all to run in an on-premise environment, I simply refer to the executable (.net console application) in the process task using it's local path.  How do I go about moving that to the cloud and running the exe in Azure?

Do I store the .exe in blob storage?  How do I call it from the SSIS package?  MS appears to suggest that Azure supports running process tasks here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/control-flow/execute-process-task?view=sql-server-ver15

Is it possible, or should I start looking at an alternative way of running this task?

Comment: Hi @R2Bleep2, any specific reason you have exe. Would .net code in script task in ssis be an option?

Comment: This article show how to implement a custom setup. In summary, you can copy files on to your Azure SSIS runtime, I'm not sure what the path to call them would be, and not aure if you would have sufficient access. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/how-to-configure-azure-ssis-ir-custom-setup#standard-custom-setup

Comment: What you are looking for is probably "Custom Activity", have a look at this blog article: https://mrpaulandrew.com/2018/11/12/creating-an-azure-data-factory-v2-custom-activity/

Comment: Update:  We've resolved this by separating the console app and running it as a web job on a separate schedule to the SSIS ETL.  Fortunately it was easy to separate the two.  In future - with new projects we would likely use a script task.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to put the executables in Azure Files. Locate the executable like \YourAzureStorageAccountName.file.core.windows.net\YourFolderName\test.exe, and provide Authentication with https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/ssis-azure-connect-with-windows-auth for Azure Files

Comment: I doubt that would work since there's no compute engine with Azure storage... what would process the .exe?

Comment: SSIS integration runtime in ADF is the engine to execute SSIS package, where SSIS execute process task will execute this .exe